# Use variable in JPA Annotation for a tablename

Tags: class, jpa, dynamic, entity, tablename

I have a database with tables created dynamically (These tables have the same structure but their name is suffixed with the year followed by the number of the current month: data201201, data201202, data201203 ...)
I created a entity-class called Data that defines the structure of these tables. I do not know how to make dynamic its use.
Please, I want you to help me!
Thanks!

Comment: A large table can be indexed for performance into ranges of values in a column such as monthly or yearly. If you have a date column in your table, you could create multiple indices for values in this column, one index per a month range of dates. Make use of indices based on your most frequent ways of accessing the information. That's how you solve efficiency problems with database - not by creating multiple tables breaking normalization!

Comment: What @ADTC said. Whenever I hear of a db schema containing a variable number of tables I know someone is missing fundamental relational database principles.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without creating a class for every table, but this would be an idea as bad as having a table for each month. The best advice is to normalize your schema by storing all the information in a single table having a `year` and a `month` column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Initially, the data was in a single table. the size of this table was becoming more and more large and made ​​access difficult (These are in fact the geographical positions of the trucks). That has forced us to cut the table in monthly tables

Comment: If the table is properly indexed on the year and month, accessing it shouldn't be significatly slower than accessing a single table holding only one month of data. Check your table indices.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use EclipseLink's dynamic Entity, or multi-tenacy table per tenant support for this.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm

Also, some databases such as Oracle support table partitioning, so that you don't need a new physical table per month.

You could also define a view that selects from the current month, to unions the relevant months, and map to the view.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible change mapping at runtime. In you case you can union all all your tables in one, and use combination of [@Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html) and [@DiscriminatorColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html) instead

**EDIT**

you combined table is

```
GLOBAL_DATE_TABLE
{
number : ID
varchar : MONTH <- this will be discriminator column
varchar : NAME
... all another fields
}
```

your mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GLOBAL_DATE_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="MONTH", discriminatorType=STRING)
public class Date 
{ 
   @Column(name = "ID")
   @Id 
   private long id;   

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   // another fields
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("data201201")
public class Data201201
{
   // if column MONTH contains value "ata201201" this instance will be created
   // logic for this table here   
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("data201202")
public class Data201202
{
   // if column MONTH contains value "ata201202" this instance will be created
   // logic for this table here    
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("data201203")
public class Data201203
{
   // if column MONTH contains value "ata201203" this instance will be created
   // logic for this table here     
}
```

Comment: Please, can you explain by an exemple? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for details. Please, in my case, these tables are created every end of the current month and this continues over time!